# Is there any way duplicated sequential string delete in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I got strings like

`String1=277473—-2627272———-273-3838383-/./--asdfg-----123:12:2---`

I cant take length of function because I have multiple strings with different lenghts.

I wanted to use split function to take them as a variable but I need this format

`String1=277473-2627272—273-3838383-/./-asdfg-123:12:2`

Is there any way to do that easily?

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 different kind of '-' characters, use this instead:

```kotlin
fun formatString(string: String): String {
   return string.mapNotNull { char -> if (char == '—' || char == '-') '-' else char }
        .joinToString(separator = "")
        .replace("""-+""".toRegex(), "-")
        .trimDashes()
}

fun String.trimDashes(): String = dropWhile { it == '-' }
    .dropLastWhile { !it.isDigit() }
```

Comment: this works only my last part of string is number,if my data ends like  this String1=277473—-2627272———-273-3838383-/./--asdfg-----123:12:2- aaaaasdqw-- takes strings until 123:12:2

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```kotlin
fun formatString(string: String): String {
   return string.trimDashes()
        .split("-")
        .joinToString(separator = "-", transform = String::trimDashes)
}

fun String.trimDashes(): String = dropWhile { it == '-' }
    .dropLastWhile { !it.isDigit() }
```

Comment: Still have same issue with this code .I updated my variables.I just need remove extra "-" between variables than I can split.